# During the laning phase, when should you take your lane's turret?

Tags: league-of-legends

This question has always bothered me while playing League of Legends. If I win my lane and take an early turret, I give myself the opportunity to roam at the cost of letting my opponent free farm their lane. While roaming benefits my team's other lanes, it also allows my lane to be counter-pushed and the turret taken.

However, if I choose not to take my opponent's turret, I force them into a somewhat dangerous position, as farming now leaves them open to ganks. As a counter point, though, doing so forces you to stay in your lane, lest your opponent push it and take your turret.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely situational.

When I definitely win my lane, I leave their turret up so I can get more kills against them. O the other hand, if I'm losing the lane, I like to take the turret down ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

For top lane and mid turrets I like to take them down asap because it allows me to roam and secure ganks and kills with my jungle. What you do is push your lane to the destroyed turret then leave your lane to gank other lanes or claim objectives.

For bot lane; even if I am winning hard I keep the turret up as long as possible because I need the farm to be a hyper carry late game. So I'll get the turret to maybe 20% then never hit it again unless it needs to go down so we can start working towards the nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I take the tower late because if you keep the turret up it becomes harder for the other team to get good cs and when they are death the towers kill creeps very fast so they get less exps, money and cs.

Answer (score 0):

Situational: Take it ASAP if you are losing, as you may not get a chance later. If you are winning, and feel that you can continue to pressure the enemy, leave it up.

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as an answer posted over a year ago. It would be great if you could add some more details to make your answer better than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Take them down ASAP

### Why?

A mid lane turret loses/gives you a lot of map control: one thing common to many of my losing games is the enemy outer mid lane turret still being up but ours being down

If this comes down, you can push to the inner without exposing yourself too much. The enemy is forced to farm the pushing minions or lose the tower to minion attrition.

So mid: ASAP.

For bot, I would consider leaving the enemy one up so I can farm. However, this gives a risk of losing my own tower after a trade that results in death or recall. So, on balance, I'd get it down ASAP. Again, the inner tower can be pushed too.

So bot: ASAP

And the same for top.

Basically, leaving the enemy tower up means:

- you can lose yours more easily because the enemy can be closer to it
- loss of map control
- keeps enemy busy
- sets you up for backdooring/splitpushing

Downsides?

- lack of farm. Maybe
- pushing means extending yourself. You ward, right?